# How to set rulerformat to align left and full width in vim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, ruler

I use ruler format like this,

```
set rulerformat=%36(%5l,%-6(%c%V%)\ %f%)%*
```

[image]

However, if the filename gets too long, it will be broken. So I like to align left, but It can't be align like statusline `%=`.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure the ruler was built for that. If you need that, you want to use the statusline

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thank you for your reply. Yeah I thought same thing, and I want to know why this is impossible then.